# Merge tags: [proj4] -> [proj]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Over on GIS.se [proj4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proj4) and [proj.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proj.4) are synonyms for [proj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proj)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/proj/synonyms

These tags are for PROJ (https://proj.org). The "4" sometimes appears in this name for an older version 4 of the library, a version that persisted for too many decades.